# Upgrading from Rails 3.2 -> 4.0, Mongoid 3 -> 5: ObjectID containing spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm upgrading an existing project from Rails 3.2 -> 4.0 and from Mongoid 3 -> 5.

ObjectIDs from my existing mongodb (2.6) now containing spaces?
How can I change that globally? Never saw this before, don't know where to search.

```
>> BSON::ObjectId.new
=> BSON::ObjectId('56 1e 13 c3 84 f5 fa 99 0d 00 00 00')

>> BSON::ObjectId.new.to_s
=> "56 1e 14 eb 84 f5 fa 99 0d 00 00 01"
```

I used to have ObjectIDs like this (working, if overridden in model):

```
>> BSON::ObjectId.new.to_s.delete(' ')
=> "561e152684f5fa990d000002"
```

Thank you very much in advance!